# why does printing a char array return the contents instead of the memory adress

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, cout

```
char array[2] = {'1', 0 };
std::cout << array;
```

Why does it output the contents and not the memory adress, aren't arrays pointers ?

Comment: Yes, arrays are pointers. It output the contents of the array because that's what the `<<` overload for character pointers does.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Arrays are not pointers. But there are many cases (like passing to a function) where an array will *decay* into a pointer to the first element.